# Angular2 : How to display image to HTML from JSON API

Tags: javascript, html, json, ionic2

I am new to Ionic and currently developing an e-commerce mobile app. I am using JSON API, I can get all the data from the API except the image, I cannot display the image coming from the JSON API. I have no idea how can I display the image to my HTML. Hope anyone can help me, thank you in advance. Here is how the JSON API looks like:

```
product: [
        {
        prod_id: 1,
        supplier_id: 8,
        prod_name: "Hippo + Friends Baby Boy Triangle Merino Pant",
        prod_price: "250",
        prod_stock: "20",
        prod_image: "assets/img/4ef1ef51ef6e2f0142452af60048df44Merino Pants.jpg"
    }
    ]
```

Comment: prod_image just returns a string to a relative path, you actually don't get the image back in this api, just a reference string to the image. You can send the image back as a blob type and then display it

Comment: thanks for the response, can I ask how can I send the image as a blob type in PHP?

Comment: I am not too familiar with PHP, so I would not be much of a help here, if you can't find a solution perhaps ask another question with a more defined scope

Comment: It's fine, thank you very much for the response.

Comment: You need to send json like this from the server. if you want to reduce your code. prod_image: "http : //serveraddress/filepath/filename" otherwise it will return as a string.

Comment: as @rahulpatel said, your image can be shown if is hosted in a server or 
 convert it as base64

Comment: you can use url from the server or follow the answer which is given by @VtoCorleone, both methods are simple. no need to convert base64.

Answer (score 1):

.html file

```
<img [src]="getImageUri(product.prod_image)"
     alt="Image preview...">
```

.ts file

```
getImageUri(image: string): string {
  if (!image) {
    image = `/assets/img/noimage.jpg`;
  }

  const uri = `${environment.assets}/${image}`;
  return uri;
}
```

`environment.assets` would be the host location of the image.

Example `environment.assets = http://hostlocation.com/images;`

I'm assuming since this is an e-commerce site that you aren't bundling your images with the app as they will be handled through some kind of CMS.

Answer (score 0):

Tou can bind it to img tag:

```
<div *ngFor="let pr of product">
    <img [src]="pr.prod_image" />
<div>
```

If you don't host image and want to send it by api you can embed bytes to image tag as base64 string:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64, BytesHere=="  />
```

Comment: I think his question was more related to getting the image back from the API as opposed to binding it

Comment: It can be done with base64 string containin image bytes and background image style.

Comment: Thank you @YD1m, I already tried base64 but did not work for me. <img [src]="DomSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl('data:image/JPEG;base64,' + item.image)"  alt="..." >

Answer (score 0):

You can send the image url via json response and use standard `<img src="...">` to fetch and display the image from the server.